# should never have been led to

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

> Of course it is not by argument that we originally come by our belief
>   in an independent external world. We find this belief ready in
>   ourselves as soon as we begin to reflect: it is what may be called an
>   instinctive belief. We **should never have been led to** question this
>   belief  but for the fact that, at any rate in the case of sight, it
>   seems as if the sense-datum itself were instinctively believed to be
>   the independent object, whereas argument shows that the object cannot
>   be identical with the sense-datum.

[Problems of Philosophy, Bertrand Russell, Chapter II]

Does "should never have been led to" have the same meaning as "would never have been led to"?

Comment: No. [Would](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would) and [should](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should) are different words and have different meanings.

Answer (score -1):

> **Could have + past participle** means that something was possible in the
>   past, or you had the ability to do something in the past, but that you
>   didn't do it.
>
> **Should have + past participle** can mean something that would have been
>   a good idea, but that you didn't do it. It's like giving advice about
>   the past when you say it to someone else, or regretting what you did
>   or didn't do when you're talking about yourself.
>
> Because 'would' (and will) can also be used to show if you want to do
>   something or not (volition), we can also use **would have + past
>   participle** to talk about something you wanted to do but didn't.

In your case, using "would never have been led to" instead of "should never have been led to" will make the meaning of the sentence change. They don't have same meaning.

Comment: The quoted meaning of "should have", while not wrong, is not the only meaning, and decidedly does not apply in this context at all.